# Converting primitive classes to basic Element? Java

Tags: java, element

So I have to write a class that extends the ArrayList class making it into a stack. The problem I'm having is with my pop method. It's saying I can't set E result to this.get because it says Object can't be converted to E? How can I make this work or do something similar to save the first index as a variable.

```
public class ArrayListStack<E> extends ArrayList implements Stack<E> {

    int size = 0;

    public void push (E element) {
        add(0, element);
    }

    public E pop() {
        E result = get(0);
        size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `size++` do there? I think the `size()` method of `ArrayList` works great

Comment: Yes, I realized that after and took it out

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
public class ArrayListStack<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements Stack<E> {
```

**Edit**

Or even better:

```
public class ArrayStack<E> extends ArrayDeque<E> implements Stack<E> {
```